# Writing to file from sql rows

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm attempting to write to a file from a function that returns several SQL rows. The issue I'm having is I only get one row back with `return` and 0 rows back if I use `echo` or `printf`

This is from `cron.php`

```
<?php
require 'lib/app.php';
//All pilots
$str = $mining->activePilots(0);
$file = fopen('elements/pilots.html',"w");
fwrite($file,$str);
fclose($file);
```

This is from the method:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) 
{ 
     $pilot = $row['username'];
     $ship = $row['ship'];
     $role = $user->opRole($row['role']);
     $hours = $row['hours'];
   return "<tr><td>$role</td><td>$pilot</td><td>$ship</td><td>$hours</td></tr>";
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Return` ends the execution of your program and passes the value obtained in the first loop. You should store the different values inside a variable and then in the end return all:

```
$store='';

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) 
    { 
         $pilot = $row['username'];
         $ship = $row['ship'];
         $role = $user->opRole($row['role']);
         $hours = $row['hours'];
       $store=$store."<tr><td>$role</td><td>$pilot</td><td>$ship</td><td>$hours</td></tr>";
     }
return $store;
```

Comment: Works beautifully! Thank you!